# Alternative to Sendy for email campaign or any other suggestions

Tags: email, amazon-web-services

I am using AWS SES to send out mails for campaign. I want to have some user interface where I can draft and send emails to subscribers. Currently I am using the Sendy for this. As sendy is in still development stage, it's not fit for me. Is there any alternative to sendy? Any service which can be integrated for AWS SES? Or can I use workmails for this?

Answer (score 1):

Now Sendy is much more mature and have added some very useful features. Also, many of product features are stable now. You can give this a try, hosting it from EasySendy. You can also integrate Mandrill with Sendy at EasySendy.